# Adding a space between two ACF fields

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) to add certain classes to a . Here's how it looks currently:

```
<div class="card <?= get_sub_field('colour'); echo ' '.get_sub_field('align_text'); ?>">
```

As I'm adding multiple classes, I need a space between the `colour` and `align_text` field.

What's the correct way to add spaces in this scenario? I feel like my method is a bit hacky.

Comment: `<div class="card <?= get_sub_field('colour') ?> <?= get_sub_field('align_text') ?>">`

Comment: That works, but I'd rather not close PHP and reopen it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="card <?= get_sub_field('colour').' '.get_sub_field('align_text'); ?>">
```